Fuzzy match on large dataset- speed up and keep similar matches
I have two beer datasets; one is ~3 million entries, and another is 175 thousand entries. Doing a fuzzy match on these two will take way too long. I've run a few tests on the same 1000 random sample entires on google colab and can't figure out a good path forward:
Test 1
Regular fuzzy matching using thefuzz takes 6.5 to 8.5 minutes and uses 10.5 gb of the 50.99 gb of ram I have. This obviously won't scale when doing 175k x 3m
Test 2
Splitting into multiple files by similar characteristics (e.g., similar beer styles, so one file has IPAs and Pale ales, another has stouts, etc.) takes even longer even though there are fewer comparisons to do using the same matching library.
Test 3
Only matching those with exact same beer style (so if one data set calls it an ipa and the other calls it a pale ale they won't get matched even though they have the same beer name). This takes about 45 seconds and seems the most promising. but still probably won't scale to the whole data set
Test 4
Utilizing rapidfuzz. It's similar speed to test 3 but the results seem much worse for my use case.
Questions
1 any suggestion on how to utilize more ram given I have about 5x to use on google colab
2 any suggestion on how to get good results but make this not take days to run
p.s. I am a beginner coder; I don't understand a lot, and my code isn't perfect. Thank you for any help in advanced!
Each of these tests has slightly different code but here the code for test 3 (just the fuzzy match section not the entire file)
type here
from concurrent.futures import ThreadPoolExecutor, as_completed
from thefuzz import fuzz, process
import re

def preprocess_names(text):
    return re.sub(r'\bclone\b', '', text, flags=re.IGNORECASE).strip()

recipes_df['cleaned_name'] = recipes_df['name'].apply(preprocess_names)
recipes_df['style_key'] = recipes_df['style'].str.lower()  # Normalize the style strings

# Expanded list of generic beer types to exclude as sole matches
generic_beer_types = {'ipa', 'pale ale', 'stout', 'ale', 'american pale ale', 'baltic porter', 'irish stout', 'imperial red', 'oktoberfest', 'lager', 'pilsner', 'porter', 'saison', 'tripel', 'bitter', 'kolsch', 'doppelbock', 'winter ale', 'pumpkin', 'vanilla', 'altbier', 'kristallweizen', 'original', 'betelgeuse', 'blueberry', 'winter ale', 'hefeweizen', 'octoberfest', 'kellerbier', 'barleywine', 'grisette', 'festbier', 'kellerbier', 'blueberry'}

def fuzzy_match(name, style, choices):
    if not choices:  # Return None early if there are no choices to compare against
        return name, (None, 0)
    
    scores = [
        process.extractOne(name, choices, scorer=fuzz.ratio),
        process.extractOne(name, choices, scorer=fuzz.token_set_ratio),
        process.extractOne(name, choices, scorer=fuzz.partial_ratio),
        process.extractOne(name, choices, scorer=fuzz.token_sort_ratio)
    ]
    scores = [score for score in scores if score]  # Filter out None results
    if not scores:  # If all scores are None, return no match
        return name, (None, 0)
    
    # Get the best match
    best_match = max(scores, key=lambda x: x[1])
    # Avoid matches that are too generic, too short, or don't represent a significant portion of the full name
    match_length_ratio = len(best_match[0]) / len(name)
    if best_match[0].lower() in generic_beer_types or len(best_match[0]) <= 6 or match_length_ratio < 0.5:
        return name, (None, 0)
    return name, best_match

def execute_parallel_fuzzy_matching(sample_reviews, recipes):
    results = {}
    grouped_reviews = sample_reviews.groupby('style_key')
    grouped_recipes = recipes.groupby('style_key')
    
    for style, review_group in grouped_reviews:
        choices = grouped_recipes.get_group(style)['cleaned_name'].tolist() if style in grouped_recipes.groups else []
        with ThreadPoolExecutor(max_workers=10) as executor:
            future_to_match = {executor.submit(fuzzy_match, row['cleaned_name'], style, choices): row['cleaned_name'] for index, row in review_group.iterrows()}
            for future in as_completed(future_to_match):
                name, result = future.result()
                results[name] = result
    return results

# Prepare the data
reviews_df['cleaned_name'] = reviews_df['name'].apply(preprocess_names)
reviews_df['style_key'] = reviews_df['style'].str.lower()  # Normalize the style strings

# Extracting a sample for testing
sample_reviews = reviews_df.sample(10000, random_state=42)

# Execute parallel fuzzy matching
matches = execute_parallel_fuzzy_matching(sample_reviews, recipes_df)

# Filter and log the high confidence matches
high_confidence_matches = {k: v[0] for k, v in matches.items() if v[1] > 90 and v[0] is not None}

print("Total initial high confidence matches:", len(matches))
print("Filtered high confidence matches count:", len(high_confidence_matches))

print("High Confidence Matches:")
for name, match in high_confidence_matches.items():
    print(f"{name} to {match} with score {matches[name][1]}")


A set of code that runs faster either through utilizing more ram or a better library / matching algo, but still maintaining a similar amount and similar quality of matches as I have on my slower code

Is fuzz.ratio ever greater than fuzz.partial_ratio? I honestly don't know but if partial_ratio is always at least as high as ratio then you might not have to do both.

do you have to do a fuzzy match with so much data available ?
